# flutter: very low res image using imagePicker

Tags: android, image, flutter

im using the image_picker to pick images from the users phone, but as soon as the image is picked it will appear very low res.

[image: very pixelated and lowres image]

is there any way this can be solved? i want to use better quality pictures but i cannot figure it out! this is the code to display the image and use the image picker:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:uni_markt/models/product.dart';

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
 final Function setImage;
 final Product product;

ImageInput(this.setImage, this.product);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ImageInputState();
  }
}

 class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
 File _imageFile;

 void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
 ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 400).then((File image) {
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = image;
  });
  widget.setImage(image);
  Navigator.pop(context);
});
}

  void _openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Pick an Image source',
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.art_track,
                  size: 90,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  _getImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Icon(
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      size: 70,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _getImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
           ],
         ),
       );
      },
    );
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Color color = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;

Widget previewImage = Text('Please select an image');
if (_imageFile != null) {
  previewImage = Image.file(_imageFile,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 300,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
} else if (widget.product != null) {
  previewImage = Image.network(widget.product.image,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 300,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
}

return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    OutlineButton(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: color, width: 3),
      onPressed: () {
        _openImagePicker(context);
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.camera_alt,
            color: color,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            'Add Image',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: color,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
    previewImage,

  ],
);
```

i think im overlooking something, but im usnure of what. can someone please help to solve this?

Comment: When you are calling ImagePicker.pickImage, you are specifying the max width to be 400. If the original image is of higher resolution(as it is in your case), picker will scale it down such that its width is 400. Simply, removing maxWidth parameter will give you image with the original resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) has a parameter [`imageQuality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker/pickImage.html):

> The imageQuality argument modifies the quality of the image, ranging
> from 0-100 where 100 is the original/max quality. If `imageQuality` is
> null, the image with the original quality will be returned.

So aside from `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`, you can also do something like this:

```
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 400, imageQuality: 100,)
```

And take note of the current implementation of the image_picker 0.8.4:

```
Future<XFile?> pickImage(
       {required ImageSource source,
       double? maxWidth,
       double? maxHeight,
       int? imageQuality,
       CameraDevice preferredCameraDevice = CameraDevice.rear}
)
```

> Old API:
>
> ```
> PickedFile image = await _picker.getImage(...)
> ```
>
> New API:
>
> ```
> XFile image = await _picker.pickImage(...)
> ```